# Showing horizontal bar for datagridview for overflowing cell content

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

[image]

My datagridview abbreviates the rest of the string when the cell is too small to contain the string.

How do I make it so that a horizontal scrollbar is shown so that the content can be viewed?

The datagridview is docked (fill) to the form and has a single column header with fill property as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Body">
<ItemTemplate>
 <div style="overflow:auto; height: 100px;">
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Body")%>'></asp:Label>
 </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Use in this way in your gridview inorder to set the overflowing data. This shows the scrollbars.

Comment: Sorry, it's Winforms but if there's absolutely no way in Winforms, I will mark this as answer and use WPF control

Comment: Okay I'll try to figure out what you need